# Create a generator which returns two values at once in Julia

Tags: julia, generator

Given a generator:

```
myVec1 = rand(0:4, 2)
myVec2 = rand(0:4, 8)

myGen = (val1 + val2 for val1 in myVec1, val2 in myVec2)
```

This is basically a matrix with 2 columns. It can be seen by using `collect(myGen)`.

How can I create a generator which yields two values per call (basically a column)?

Conceptually, something equivalent of:

```
for myCol in eachcol(collect(myGen))
    @show myCol;
end
```

Just without any explicit allocation of the matrix.

Can I wrap `myGen` for the following case:

```
for value1, value2 in myGen
  dosomethingelse1(value1, value2)
end
```

In other words, I am after a way to create a generator which returns 2 (or more?) consecutive values at once and can be used in a loop to do so.

So basically, we create a 2D array in the generator and I'd like to access the whole slice at once. I could do it with `eachcol` and `eachrow` for actual array, but what about the generator?

Here is a test case:

```
myVec1 = rand(0:4, 2);
myVec2 = rand(0:4, 800);

@btime begin
    myMat = [val1 + val2 for val1 in myVec1, val2 in myVec2];
    outVec = [sum(myCol) for myCol in eachcol(myMat)];
end

@btime begin
    myGen = (val1 + val2 for val1 in myVec1, val2 in myVec2);
    outVec = [sum(myCol) for myCol in Iterators.partition(myGen, 2)];
end
```

The solution by @Bogumił Kamiński indeed works, yet in practice, for some reason, it creates more allocations while the motivation was to reduce it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the other answers are in some ways more general based on the information added by OP in their edits a more memory efficient option would be using nested generators. Something like:

```
function solution_nested(v1, v2)
    myGen = ((val1 + val2 for val1 in v1) for val2 in v2)
    [sum(myCol) for myCol in myGen]
end
```

When you test the solutions you should avoid using global variables and preferably wrap the solution in a function so you give Julia sufficient opportunity to optimize the code.

This solution gives the expected result of only one allocation:

```
julia> @btime solution_nested(myVec1, myVec2);
  1.856 μs (1 allocation: 6.38 KiB)
```

So while this solution does not quite fit the title it seems to fit what you are describing. We use a lazy sequence of lazy columns. The reason `Iterators.partition` is slow and memory inefficient is that it actually allocates the intermediate vectors of values in a partition: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/dacf9d65aff4668b8fff25957d9aaa2cf03868c8/base/iterators.jl#L1232 .

Comment: Is the only allocation in your solution the allocation of the output?

Answer (score 5):

I assume you want something like:

```
julia> for (x1, x2) in Iterators.partition(1:10, 2)
           @show x1, x2
       end
(x1, x2) = (1, 2)
(x1, x2) = (3, 4)
(x1, x2) = (5, 6)
(x1, x2) = (7, 8)
(x1, x2) = (9, 10)
```

If this is what you want then `Iterators.partition` is a function you can use.

Edit: If you have two streams of sources use `zip`:

```
julia> for (x1, x2) in zip(1:5, 6:10)
           @show x1, x2
       end
(x1, x2) = (1, 6)
(x1, x2) = (2, 7)
(x1, x2) = (3, 8)
(x1, x2) = (4, 9)
(x1, x2) = (5, 10)
```

Edit 2: my first solution works already for your case:

```
julia> collect(myGen)
2×8 Matrix{Int64}:
 3  7  5  4  6  3  4  5
 1  5  3  2  4  1  2  3

julia> for (x1, x2) in Iterators.partition(myGen, 2)
           @show x1, x2
       end
(x1, x2) = (3, 1)
(x1, x2) = (7, 5)
(x1, x2) = (5, 3)
(x1, x2) = (4, 2)
(x1, x2) = (6, 4)
(x1, x2) = (3, 1)
(x1, x2) = (4, 2)
(x1, x2) = (5, 3)
```

Comment: I updated my question. Will it still fit?

Comment: I have updated the answer, but I am still not 100% if this is what you want. Can you please share a working example of your source data and an expected output?

Comment: I created a simple case. Can you look at it? The `zip` trick won't work for it.

Comment: It does not work, as my first solution seems to do what you wanted in that case.

Comment: Indeed it works, but for some reason it doesn't reduce the number of allocations. Any idea?

Comment: The issue is that that your `myGen` generator is not type stable to start with (you can check it by wrapping your code in a function and using `@code_warntype`). If you want fast code use an explicit `for` loop instead and do not use generator.

Comment: Are you sure that's the case? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71752338.

Comment: The comment you linked is correct. However, it seems that `Iterators.partition` not only allocates - as was commented there - but also is type unstable for some reason(and this is what I saw earlier and now I re-checked and I see it again).

Answer (score 4):

This is supported directly by Julia syntax. Iterating over generators of tuples works like interating over atomic values.

For an example you could try:

```
for (a,b) in ((x, 3x) for x in 1:4)
    println("a=$a, b=$b")
end
```

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify. It is not that the called function returns 2 values but the generator works as 2D.

Comment: Do you mean a Cartesian Product that can be achieved via `IterTools.product` ?

Answer (score 1):

You're basically missing brackets when destructuring the tuple of values in the second loop. To be more detailed, you can just return two values (a tuple) in your `dosomething` function. For example:

```
function dosomething(element)
    secondElement = element^2
    element, secondElement
end
```

And then you can use the loop by destructuring the return value, like so:

```
for (value1, value2) in myGen
    dosomethingelse(value1, value2)
end
```

If you want a full working example:

```
myArray = [1, 2, 3]

function dosomething(element)
    secondElement = element^2
    element, secondElement
end

myGen = (dosomething(myElement) for myElement in myArray)

function dosomethingelse(value1, value2)
    println("Value 1: $value1 \nValue 2: $value2 \n")
end

for (value1, value2) in myGen
    dosomethingelse(value1, value2)
end
```

---

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify. It is not that the called function returns 2 values but the generator works as 2D.